# Post-Build Event / Task for launch profile?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I am trying to build a remote debugging workflow for an C#/WPF app.

I followed the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022 and for reasons is cannot fathom, VS does not automatically copy the compiled binaries to the remote machine where they are needed, it has to be done manualy.

Thus, I am trying to attach a task to the launchsettings (found in `Properties\launchSettings.json`).

After configuring the launch profile as shown in the instructions, the json looks like this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyCoolApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": false,
      "authenticationMode": "Windows",
      "remoteDebugMachine": ""
    },
    "MyCoolAppRemote": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": true,
      "authenticationMode": "Windows",
      "remoteDebugMachine": "<remote-pc-name>:4026"
    }
  }
}
```

Can I just put a script block with robocopy in here somewhere to copy the build dir?
Can I somehow reference the current launc profile in the .csproj to define a PostBuildTask there?

Or is there really no way to do this and I need to copy this manually every time?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I'm interested doing the same

Comment: Unfortunately not. I now have a normal post-build event in the csproj that runs after every compile and checks if the target network share is present, and if it is, copies the files. 

It isn’t perfect, it adds some latency to every build process, even if it’s not remote, but it’s the best I found.